# Importing next years date to table based on max number in year column , my code freezes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with duplicate company names , as they each have a row of data based on yearly values. I have been trying to create an import code to add a row for each company with the next year details added. My code filters column E which has the year , from smallest to largest number. I use the max code to get the first instance of the highest number. and then I get the last row number and last row number plus 1 values. I can then copy and paste the range to the next empty row. I then need clear the range in column H and columns N to AD. I need to ensure that the columns J:K are in the dd/mm/yyyy format for my code to change the years only for dates in columns J and K. my code below works , but it can take 20 to 30 mins to run. and can freeze up. My computer spec is quite good , so not sure why this small bit of code is taking so long. Any help would be much appreciated , as I have spent hours looking for a solution.

```
Sub AddNewYear()
othwb = Application.Workbooks.Count
If othwb > 1 Then MsgBox "Please save and close any other workbooks before running this code", , "Panda": Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim d As Date
Dim da As Date
Dim lrow As Long
Dim copy_range As Range
lrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Financial Data").Range("J2", "K200000") = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
lrow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim tabl As ListObject
Set tabl = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
Sheet1.ListObjects.item(1).ShowTotals = False
Dim orgid As String
Dim yearchoice As Variant
tabl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
yearchoice = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("E:E"))
Set copy_range = Sheet1.Range("A2:AZ" & lrow)
tabl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=yearchoice
copy_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet1.Range("A" & lrow1)
tabl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Dim lrow2
lrow2 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("H" & lrow1 & ":H" & lrow2).ClearContents
Sheet1.Range("N" & lrow1 & ":AD" & lrow2).ClearContents
Dim x
yearchoice = yearchoice + 1
For x = lrow1 To lrow2
Sheet1.Range("E" & x).Value = yearchoice
Sheet1.Range("F" & x).Value = "A"
Sheet1.Range("G" & x).Value = yearchoice & Sheet1.Range("F" & x).Value
Sheet1.Range("H" & x).Value = 0
d = Sheet1.Range("J" & x).Value
Sheet1.Range("J" & x).Value = DateSerial(year(d) + 1, Month(d), Day(d))
da = Sheet1.Range("K" & x).Value
Sheet1.Range("K" & x).Value = DateSerial(year(da) + 1, Month(da), Day(da))
Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It will be easier if you can provide an input sample. We don´t know how big is your range.

Comment: There are currently 15568 rows of data , with 1386 rows to be copied and pasted . There columns A:BA

Comment: it appears to be this line of code causing issues Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Financial Data").Range("J2", "K200000") = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: Should be `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Financial Data").Range("J2", "K200000").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`